# How to render BitmapFont.fnt with java.awt.Graphics2D?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, bitmap-fonts

I should load bitmap font before I use it to draw text with java.awt.Graphics2D

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics graphics) {
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    graphics.setFont(awtFont); // font should be loaded before it can be used
    graphics.drawString("text", 0, 0);
}
```

Following code loads bitmap font "BitmapFont.fnt"

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Font awtFont;  
        InputStream fontResource = Runner.class.getResourceAsStream("BitmapFont.fnt");
        try {
            awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontResource);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try{
                awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TYPE1_FONT, fontResource);
            }catch (Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

throws an exceptions

```
java.awt.FontFormatException: Unsupported sfnt C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Temp\+~JF454779897929138835.tmp
at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(TrueTypeFont.java:488)
at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:162)
at sun.font.FontManager.createFont2D(FontManager.java:2474)
at java.awt.Font.<init>(Font.java:570)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:896)
at com.test.Runner.main(Runner.java:12)
```

and

```
 java.awt.FontFormatException: bad pfa font
at sun.font.Type1Font.verifyPFA(Type1Font.java:298)
at sun.font.Type1Font.verify(Type1Font.java:276)
at sun.font.Type1Font.<init>(Type1Font.java:148)
at sun.font.FontManager.createFont2D(FontManager.java:2477)
at java.awt.Font.<init>(Font.java:570)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:896)
at com.test.Runner.main(Runner.java:12)
```

respectively. How to load BitmapFont.fnt and render it with java.awt.Graphics2D?

Comment: Try specifying a [`TYPE1_FONT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#TYPE1_FONT) instead of `TRUETYPE_FONT`.  BTW - what does this have to do with Swing?

Comment: is Font (and how is) register Font to local enviroment

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, because I miss there two-three important code lines

Comment: please where is registerFont used

Comment: it is used inside JPanel paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics graphics) callback to draw text

Comment: graphics.setFont(awtFont); graphics.drawString("text", 0, 0);